# Is it possible to lauch android wifi settings by url scheme through web browser?

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I want to add a link tag in a webpage, and when user clicks it through an android device browser, I hope the android wifi settings interface would open. I've tried following adb command and it worked:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings`

and I tried to transform the command into url scheme, after reading [Android Intents with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents), I tried with code below:

`<a href="intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;component=com.android.settings/.Settings;end">Open Wifi Settings</a>`

it still won't work.

Could anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: this is for launching any application from chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

Activities that can be invoked from a browser must support category: BROWSABLE
    
AFAIK Setting doesn't support it