# Opening Location Settings Activity from Chrome on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, browser, location

I am trying to open location settings from Chrome (on Android) on a button click using [Android Intents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). I am following the Barcode Scanner example and tried encoding the url similar way.
For location I have tried this:-

```
const uri = "intent://com.google.android.gms.location.settings.GOOGLE_LOCATION_SETTINGS#Intent;action=com.google.android.gms.location.settings.GOOGLE_LOCATION_SETTINGS;end"
```

I also tried opening settings using this:-

```
const uri = "intent://ACTION_SETTINGS#Intent;action=android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS;end"
```

or this

```
const uri = "intent://android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS#Intent;action=android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS;end"
```

But nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

I am attaching it to a button using href tag.

Answer (score 5):

Seems you can't open Location Settings directly from Android Intents with Chrome because Settings Activities didn't support [`BROWSABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE) category (for details take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31638887/6950238) question of [Dickeylth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1661664/dickeylth) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31639042/6950238) of [Rafal Malek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380823/rafal-malek)). But You can 100% do this via custom android application and [Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html) to custom Activity with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>` support, like in [that](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking/index.html#0) tutorial.

In that case your application `SettingsActivity` code should be like:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
    }

}
```

and `AndroidManifest.xml` part for `SettingsActivity`

```
<activity android:name=".SettingsActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:host="open.location.settings"
            android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

and, finally, "deep" link for `SettingsActivity` in HTML file:

```
<a href="http://open.location.settings">Open Location Settings</a>
```

Seems, if you don't want to install app on user side, you can also do this in [Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html). Details for links to Instant App you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/instant-app-links.html).

Comment: Well my use case is for some survey/data-collection form, there is no app involved, on which I could deep link. Anyways, on seeing the answer you mentioned, I too think it won't be possible. Thanks.

Comment: @deepankar For this case you can use [Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html).

Comment: Yes instant apps seems to be nice alternative, but they work only on Android 6.0 and above. A lot of devices fall in lower category.