# How to connect to wifi from mobile browser using JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wifi, settings, android-wifi

I am trying to achieve functionality where a user inserts their wifi network name/ssid and their password and connects to that wifi straight from the browser. Is there a way to achieve this?

If not, is there a way to at least open the wifi settings from the browser? I know that their is no way to open to the wifi settings from safari on ios, but is their a way to do this using android?

Any help or direction would be much appreciated, Thank you

Comment: You can't do that see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099467/opening-location-settings-activity-from-chrome-on-android/46175726#46175726
Why don't you just make a react native application?

Comment: So I am using NFC technology to direct users to a url in the browser, where i was then hoping to redirect from there to wifi settings. Is there a way to just open the settings in android from the browser then atleast? I have figured out how to go to settings safari, just need to configure android now. Thank you for your response.